# gpg --pinentry-mode loopback too much data for the ICP layer in CLI (non-gui) mode?

Tags: gnupg, ubuntu-20.04, xubuntu, gpg-agent

When I use **X11 GUI mode**, I can enter my passphrase through the prompt without errors: `'gpg -d <my encrypted file>'`.

However, when I try the same from a CLI (windowless mode) specifying `pinentry-mode loopback`, to prevent the system from generating an X window passphrase prompt, I get the error messages.

Executing `gpg --pinentry-mode loopback -d` returns:

```
gpg: problem with the agent: Too much data for the ICP layer

gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase

gpg: decryption failed
```

I tried looking at the manuals for gpg, gpgconf, gpg-connect-agent, but I can't find a source where I could increase the size of the entered passphrase in `pinentry-mode loopback`.  I'm guessing that is the problem even though my passphrases are not even 500 characters.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.1, Xubuntu DE, 64 bit.

Comment: I assume you've already added `allow-loopback-pinentry` to `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`  also see this [Is gpg-argument `'--pinentry-mode loopback'` still necessary?](https://github.com/actions/setup-java/issues/271#issuecomment-1138404921)

Comment: @BlindSpots no I haven't, but the manual says, it is allowed by default anyway. However, if I decrypt the files from the X window and go to CLI, log in with the same user, I can just simply decrypt them with the pinentry loopback -d, and they don't even require a password or anything, they are automatically decrypted.

I guess this is a workaround?

But what if I don't have an Xterminal, but merely a CLI? The problem would persist (and still).